# Extract values from JSON objects and assign them to shell variables in a loop

Tags: json, bash, jq, zsh

I am using `jq` like below to parse a json file -

The json file looks something like -

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "email": "user1@domain.com",
      "id": "USER1_ID"
    },{
      "email": "user2@domain.com",
      "id": "USER2_ID"
    },
    .
]
}
```

I am able to print/ iterate through the ids like below

```
for k in $(cat input.json | jq .values | jq .[].id); do
    echo $k
done
```

This prints each individual id as expected.

However, what I want is to access both the email and the id in the loop.

I tried to assign values to SHELL variables like below -

```
emails=$(cat input.json | jq .values | jq .[].email)
ids=$(cat input.json | jq .values | jq .[].id)
```

This could work for the most part but `ids` can have spaces too which is breaking this.

I could essentially have to 2 for loops one for `email` and the other for `id` and assign values to arrays in the loop

```
   i=0
    for k in $(cat input.json | jq .values | jq .[].id); do
            ids[$i]=$k
            i=$(($i +1)) 
        done
```

and

```
i=0
for k in $(cat input.json | jq .values | jq .[].email); do
        emails[$i]=$k
        i=$(($i +1)) 
    done
```

Once I have both the values in arrays, I could parallely traverse both of them.

I am not a shell expert so I wanted to know if there is any slick way of doing this with fewer loops/ lines of code.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: BTW, `cat foo | anything` is pretty much always better replaced with `anything <foo` or, when the program supports it, `anything foo`. Either of these gives `anything` a direct file handle on `foo`, so it can seek around, read out-of-order, etc; this lets `sort` split into different threads to read and sort different parts of the file in parallel, or `tail` jump straight to the end, etc. By contrast, `cat` only reads front-to-back in-order, with no ability to skip.

Comment: ...and `for anything in $(...)` is itself inherently buggy; there are some differences between bash and zsh, but much of [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) applies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can output each email-ID pair as a comma separated list from JQ, and use read them into variables in a while loop like so:

```
while IFS=',' read -r email id; do
  echo "$email"
  echo "$id"
done <<EOF
$(jq -r '.values[] | "\(.email),\(.id)"' file)
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the variables don't have embedded carriage returns, you can save yourself a lot of IFS grief by having separate `read` commands for each variable, e.g.:

```
jq -r '.values[] | (.email, .id)'  input.json |
while IFS= read -r email ; do
    IFS= read -r id 
    echo "email=$email and id=$id"
done
```